# Definition of vacua in QFT in generic spacetimes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I have been learning QFT in curved spaces from various sources (Birrell/Davies, Tom/Parker, some papers), and one thing that confuses me the most is the choice of vacua in various spacetimes, and the *definition* used in various contexts. They seem to be everywhere and I am somewhat disoriented.

For convenience, I will break the question into three parts. If I have misunderstood something fundamental, I would appreciate the correction. I am not sure if it is too long as a single post, but they look connected enough to be on the same post.

**UPDATE:** it has been suggested that this question is too long (especially Part 1), but I think what I need is coherence so multiple answers that can be read together into coherent explanations will work. I am looking for basically something similar to an explanation about differences between correlators in this StackExchange post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20797/differentiating-propagator-greens-function-correlation-function-etc), which helps because most sources do not put them side by side or use the same language.

(1) **What are the definitions of the following vacua for spacetimes where you can define them?**

- Bunch-Davies vacuum
- Instantaneous vacuum
- Adiabatic vacuum
- Conformal vacuum$^\dagger$
- Unruh vacuum
- Hartle-Hawking vacuum
- Boulware vacuum
- Static vacuum*

To start with, I do know some basic ideas about how these states are defined; usually, you need to pick how to split the Hilbert space into positive and negative frequency solutions, and they are different based on boundary conditions that the eigenmodes have to satisfy (positive frequency means the Lie derivative with respect to the appropriate Killing time is proportional to the frequency); furthermore, for some states (e.g. Unruh/HH/Boulware), often the narrative is based on where the non-zero stress energy is, though strictly speaking it's a matter of what Killing time you pick. What I am more interested in is the definitions, and perhaps more importantly the distinguishing features between these states (if at all).

Only for $^\dagger$ do I know how to define it precisely, since it requires the use of conformal coupling and conformal invariance of some sort to define it, therefore it is also independent of the precise spacetime you use it on so long as the symmetry is there. For some of these, I know roughly how they work in specific spacetimes, but I am still somewhat confused, and I suspect that for some of those, they coincide. For example, Unruh/HH/Boulware is used in BH spacetimes, but if I were to switch to cosmological spacetimes with horizons, would these names be applicable? In the de Sitter case for the massless conformally coupled scalar field, some sources say adiabatic/conformal/Bunch-Davies are the same thing, though not clear how so.

Furthermore, for some vacua in say cosmological contexts, they were defined with respect to some length scale (super/subhorizon scales) which I don't understand. For static vacuum, it is a name I give it myself because I cannot find it fitting anywhere; it is the vacuum for static coordinates in de Sitter spacetimes. Does it coincide with some of these (or say if I have instead Schwarzschild-de Sitter black holes)? What about say the AdS spacetime, which is often studied in many other contexts, yet I only really heard of conformal vacuum being used in most cases (so is that Poincare coordinates?), though presumably in presence of black holes these would go back to Unruh/HH/Boulware?

(2) **Is it necessary that a good vacuum state be "Hadamard", i.e. have a particular short-distance behaviour similar to Minkowski**? It looks to me that it has to be, but I have heard that some seemingly good/well-motivated choice of states violate this condition (e.g. Sorkin-Johnston state, or some vacua in the massless minimally coupled scalar field in de Sitter --- I don't know which vacua, hence the question in Part 1)? This is one reason I removed SJ state from part 1 (for now).

(3) There have been quantization methods involving null hypersurfaces (this is done e.g. in Unruh effect derivation in Wald's text, or Frolov's null surface quantization paper). I know that strictly speaking, the choice of vacua is not about the choice of coordinates but rather the boundary conditions we put on the field modes, and some of these are very natural in some coordinates but not others. However, null slicing introduces null coordinates as natural time, and it seems to me that it would make some choice of vacua hard to define since you might be using $\mathscr{I}^\pm$ to define the boundary conditions. Even worse in the case of rotating spacetimes, where the Cauchy surface would need to include the horizons, as I think how the Frolov-Thorne vacuum (?) is defined. **Is the choice of null slicing essential for defining certain vacua, and if so for what "textbook" states are these?**

Comment: Hi @Everiana, I suggest you split this question into multiple questions for each one of the definitions from the list. As it stands, it can be too long to answer (I could answer about Unruh and Hartle-Hawking, for example, but the appearance of other terms that I don't know much about is discouraging).

Comment: I have no time to answer unfortunately. However, Yes, Hadamard is necessary for many reasons, so SJ states are ruled out. Regarding quantization of fields on null surfaces, there is an extensive rigorous literature on that subject. I wrote many papers on that. Look for my book with two colleagues about Hadamard states from lightlike surfaces (Springer 2017 I guess).

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov thanks. I think for coherence I will leave it as it is, but I would also appreciate partial answers (as you may be able to). I think what I need, whether in a single answer or not, is consistent definition applicable for standard spacetimes of interest.

Comment: @ValterMoretti thanks, I will try to look them up.

Answer (score 1):

The following should answer your 1st questions-\

- **Bunch-Davies vacuum**: This is the vacuum state for a scalar field in an expanding universe, such as the de Sitter space. It is defined by requiring that the field modes are positive frequency with respect to the conformal time, which is related to the cosmic time by a scale factor. This vacuum state is invariant under the de Sitter symmetry group and has no particle creation. It is also called the Euclidean vacuum or the conformal vacuum¹.
- **Instantaneous vacuum**: This is the vacuum state for a scalar field in a time-dependent background, such as a collapsing star. It is defined by requiring that the field modes are positive frequency with respect to the instantaneous proper time of a freely falling observer. This vacuum state is not invariant under any symmetry group and has particle creation. It is also called the in-vacuum or the natural vacuum².
- **Adiabatic vacuum**: This is the vacuum state for a scalar field in a slowly varying background, such as a perturbed de Sitter space. It is defined by requiring that the field modes are positive frequency with respect to the adiabatic time, which is a function of the background curvature and the field mass. This vacuum state is approximately invariant under the background symmetry group and has negligible particle creation. It is also called the adiabatic state or the WKB vacuum³.
- **Conformal vacuum**: This is the vacuum state for a massless scalar field in a conformally flat spacetime, such as the Minkowski space or the de Sitter space. It is defined by requiring that the field modes are positive frequency with respect to the conformal time, which is related to the proper time by a conformal factor. This vacuum state is invariant under the conformal group and has no particle creation. It is also called the Minkowski vacuum or the Bunch-Davies vacuum⁴.
- **Unruh vacuum**: This is the vacuum state for a scalar field in a black hole spacetime, such as the Schwarzschild space. It is defined by requiring that the field modes are positive frequency with respect to the Kruskal time, which is a coordinate that covers both the exterior and the interior of the black hole. This vacuum state is regular at the future horizon and has thermal radiation at the Hawking temperature. It is also called the Unruh state or the Kruskal vacuum⁵.
- **Hartle-Hawking vacuum**: This is the vacuum state for a scalar field in a black hole spacetime, such as the Schwarzschild space. It is defined by requiring that the field modes are positive frequency with respect to the Hartle-Hawking time, which is a coordinate that covers both the exterior and the interior of the black hole and is related to the Euclidean time by a Wick rotation. This vacuum state is regular at both the future and the past horizons and has thermal radiation at the Hawking temperature. It is also called the Hartle-Hawking state or the Euclidean vacuum.
- **Boulware vacuum**: This is the vacuum state for a scalar field in a black hole spacetime, such as the Schwarzschild space. It is defined by requiring that the field modes are positive frequency with respect to the Schwarzschild time, which is a coordinate that covers only the exterior of the black hole. This vacuum state is singular at the future horizon and has no radiation at infinity. It is also called the Boulware state or the Schwarzschild vacuum.
- **Static vacuum**: This is the vacuum state for a scalar field in a static spacetime, such as the Minkowski space or the Rindler space. It is defined by requiring that the field modes are positive frequency with respect to the static time, which is a coordinate that is constant along the timelike Killing vector. This vacuum state is invariant under the static symmetry group and has no particle creation. It is also called the static state or the Rindler vacuum.

You can refer to my sources-
(1) Running vacuum in quantum field theory in curved spacetime .... https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-020-8238-6.
(2) quantum field theory - What is an vacuum in QFT in curved spacetime .... [What is an vacuum in QFT in curved spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503236/what-is-an-vacuum-in-qft-in-curved-spacetime).
(3) Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime – Elementary Particle Physics. https://home.uni-leipzig.de/tet/?page_id=89.
(4) The vacuum of quantum field theories in curved spacetime. [The vacuum of quantum field theories in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/671068/the-vacuum-of-quantum-field-theories-in-curved-spacetime).
(5) Quantum field theory in curved spacetime - Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime.