# The vacuum of quantum field theories in curved spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The vacuum of a quantum field theory in flat spacetime is **postulated** to be unique for all inertial observers. If $\hat{P}_\mu$ denote the generators for spacetime translations, and $\hat{J}_{\mu\nu}$ denotes the generators of homogeneous Lorentz transformations, this postulate means $$\hat{P}_\mu|0\rangle=0, ~\hat{J}_{\mu\nu}|0\rangle=0.$$

Why can't we postulate that the vacuum is unique for all observers also in curved spacetime by demanding that the vacuum is invariant under general coordinate transformations?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation I have: even if axiomatic QFT (in flat Minkowski spacetime) places the vacuum on a pedestal by including it in one of the axioms, in "real life QFT" it is not a primordial notion, but a derived one. Namely, as soon as you find a so-called "mode expansion" of the unquantized free field, by imposing the standard quantization rule, you end up with the vacuum defined using annihilation and creation operators.

But how did you get there in the first place? The possibility of a mode expansion by "transfourier-ing" the linear classical field equation rests on one important thing:

*- the existence of a set of four rectangular coordinates which enables one to account for the needed "wave vector" with which the so-called "positive frequency modes" can be defined*.

This in turn has a neat geometrical explanation. It stems from what is known as the isometry group of the space time manifold, which for a flat Minkowski spacetime is the Poincaré group. Symmetries and **globally** conserved quantities are encoded in the so-called Killing vectors of the manifold.

The problem, of course, is that an arbitrary curved 4 D manifold has **no global Killing vectors**, thus any mode expansion (hence annihilation operators) is only local. So you cannot have a unique vacuum, even if you wanted to. You have a distinct vacuum at each point for each set of local coordinates. Different vacua means different annihilation operators which you can link through the a so-called  [Bogoliubov transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation).

This is all in some detail explained in a QFT book such as [Birrell & Davies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521278589) which builds all at an easy pace (compared to a more involved approach by [Wald](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0226870278), for which his GR book is a prerequsite).

Comment: In the italicized statement are you saying that Fourier transforming requires the existence of a global Cartesian coordinate system? If so, I could not follow why.

Comment: @Solidification to perform Fourier transforms, you need to have some sense of scalar product in spacetime, so that you can write $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}$ in the exponent. In the presence of gravity, spacetime does not admit a natural vector space structure, so that can't be done. Notice that even the metric can't allow you to perform such a computation, since it acts on vectors, not on point on spacetime. Hence, there is no natural way to use Fourier analysis when you're not on Minkowski spacetime

Comment: What is the meaning of global timelike killing vector? Is it timelike everywhere in space or are we considering the timelike killing vector as the generator of global isometry along temporal direction?

Answer (score 0):

I believe central to this question is: what really are the Poincaré generators $P_\mu$ and $J_{\mu\nu}$? The relevance is that if we wish to even think of generalizing the statement that the vacuum is invariant under $P_\mu$ and $J_{\mu\nu}$ to arbitrary diffeomorphisms, we would need to understand what is the analogue of $P_\mu$ and $J_{\mu\nu}$ for diffeomorphsisms.

The key here is to understand that $P_\mu$ and $J_{\mu\nu}$ *are the charges associated to a particular symmetry*. In the Hamiltonian formalism of Classical Mechanics, the charge $Q$ associated to a symmetry transformation $\delta_Q$ is such that $$\{Q,f\}=\delta_Q f\tag{1}.$$
This statement gets promoted, upon quantization, to the statement that there exists an operator $\hat{Q}$ in the Hilbert space of the theory, that generates the symmetry action on operators through the commutator.

A more abstract way of rewriting (1) is to recall that a phase space in Classical Mechanics is a symplectic manifold $(\Gamma,\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a two-form in $\Gamma$ which is closed, $d\Omega=0$, and non-degenerate, $\Omega(X,Y)=0$ for all $Y$ implies $X=0$. Such two-form we call a *sympletic form*. It is related to the Poisson bracket as follows: introduce coordinates $\zeta^I$ on $\Gamma$, then if $\Omega_{IJ}$ are the components of $\Omega$ in the coordinate basis, and if $\Omega^{IJ}$ is the inverse matrix, $$\{f,g\}=\Omega^{IJ}\partial_I f\partial_J g\tag{2}.$$

A symmetry transformation is now a diffeomorphism in phase space. The relation between symmetry and charge (1) can be written then as $$\Omega(X_Q,Y)=-dQ(Y)\tag{3},$$

where $X_Q$ is vector field on $\Gamma$ generating the symmetry transformation. In particular $\delta_Qf = X_Q(f)$ for some observable $f\in C^\infty(\Gamma)$.

Now observing that spacetime diffeomorphisms, a.k.a. general coordinate transformations, are local transformations, we can precisely formulate the question as *given a local symmetry of a theory in some arbitrary spacetime $(M,g)$, what is its associated charge $Q$ described in the above procedure?*

It turns out this question gets precisely answered by the so-called *Covariant Phase Space formalism* that is studied by people in the field of asymptotic symmetries for a long time. [This answer of mine gives an overview with references](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/638183/diffeomorphism-invariance-in-gr/645579#645579) and also [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719053/can-residual-gauge-symmetries-have-compact-support/725592#725592).

The moral of the story in these posts is that starting from a Lagrangian density (that could as well be the Einstein-Hilbert one) it is possible to construct an object called pre-symplectic density $\pmb{\omega}[\phi,\delta_1\phi,\delta_2\phi]$ such that the symplectic form reads $$\Omega[\phi,\delta_1\phi,\delta_2\phi]=\int_\Sigma \pmb{\omega}[\phi,\delta_1\phi,\delta_2\phi],\tag{4}$$
where $\Sigma$ is a Cauchy surface, $\phi$ are the fields in the theory and $\delta_i\phi$ are two variations that play the role of the phase space vectors. Then Noether's second theorem comes into play and it allows you to show that if $\delta_1\phi = \delta_\epsilon\phi$ is a symmetry transformation with local parameter $\epsilon(x)$, and $\delta_2\phi=\delta\phi$ is an arbitrary variation, then $\pmb{\omega}[\phi,\delta_\epsilon\phi,\delta\phi]$ is a closed form

$$\pmb{\omega}[\phi,\delta_\epsilon\phi,\delta\phi] = d\mathbf{k}_\epsilon[\phi,\delta\phi]\tag{5}$$

so that the symplectic form reads $$\Omega[\phi,\delta_\epsilon\phi,\delta\phi] = \int_{\partial\Sigma}\mathbf{k}_\epsilon[\phi,\delta\phi].\tag{6}$$

Since $\Sigma$ is a Cauchy surface, $\partial\Sigma$ lies at infinity. In fact, for asymptotically flat spacetimes, $\partial\Sigma$ is close to spatial infinity $i^0$. Now the RHS of (6) can be zero or not. If it is zero, as it happens when one demands that fields vanish at infinity in asymptotically flat spacetimes, then the associated charge $Q_\epsilon =0$ is trivial. In fact, in that case $\delta_\epsilon$ are degenerate vectors of $\Omega$ and it is not a true symplectic form: one must fix the gauge, because these transformations are not true symmetries, but mere redundancies. This is what is happening most of the time and is why demanding that these generators annihilate the vacuum do not make much sense: they are identically zero already because we don't have a true symmetry! These diffeomorphisms are called small diffeomorphisms or trivial ones.

But I must comment that it *is* possible to get a non-zero result for some diffeomorphisms, and in fact, one that allows you to eventually use (3) to define a non-trivial charge. These diffeorphisms are called large diffeomorphisms or asymptotic symmetries more generally. In asymptotically flat spacetimes they give rise to the extended BMS algebra for example.

In that case we have non-trivial charges $Q_f$ associated to super translations and $Q_Y$ associated to superstations, a subset of which recovers the Poincaré charges $P_\mu$ and $J_{\mu\nu}$. It turns out, however, that one can study what those charges do to the vacuum, and what one finds out is that apart from the Poincaré charges the other ones *do not* annihilate the vacuum. Instead, they shift the vacuum: these extra symmetries are spontaneously broken. For more details see the references in the threads I linked as well as [Andy Strominger's lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448).

I would thus summarize as follows: we can't postulate a state that is annihilated by the generators of diffeomorphisms for two reasons: (1) firstly because small diffeomorphisms are not true symmetries and they don't have non-trivial charges, (2) secondly because for large diffeomorphisms in asymptotically flat spacetimes we can check that the state annihilated by the Poincaré charges simply cannot be annihilated by the remaining extended BMS charges. Point (2) then provides a counter-example in which that proposal just does not work.